# TypeScriptでJQueryの$(function () {})を処理させるには？

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, typescript

Web系ごく初心者ですので用語の誤り、説明行き届かない点などご指摘ください．

### 背景（今までやったこと）

Laravelを使用してPHPアプリを作っています．Modelを定義して、Viewを作って、Controllerを作ってと、一通り目的のページを出力するまでたどり着きました．`index.list.blade.php`がテンプレートファイルになるのですが、ここに山ほどJavaScriptのコードを書かねばなりません．しかし、そんなことをやり始めたらロジック（JavaScript）とスタイル（というか表示出力のHTML）がグッチャングッチャンになることは目に見えています．ならばJavaScriptは別ファイルに納めてと考えたのですが、いままでちょこちょこJavaScriptの小規模なプログラムを作ってきた経験はありますが、あまりに簡単に粗雑でトリッキーなコードが書けてしまうので、こういうのは精神衛生上よろしくないと考えてVSCode+Node.jsでTypeScriptに挑戦してみました．

### 困っている点

コードをTypeScriptで書く分については、型付けができるので大変気に入っております．ところが、作成した`index.list.blade.ts`をコンパイルして`index.list.blade.js`に落とした場合、最初は次のようなエラーが出てしまいました．

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Index List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/datatables.min.css') }}"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('javascript/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('javascript/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('javascript/index.list.blade.js') }}"></script>
        ...
    </head>
```

ブラウザのエラーメッセージ：

> Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined at index.list.blade.js:20

これはWebページを参照して、`require.js`が必要なようでしたので

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Index List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/datatables.min.css') }}"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('javascript/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('javascript/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>
        <!--script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('javascript/index.list.blade.js') }}"></script-->
        <script type="text/javascript" data-main="{{ asset('javascript/index.list.blade.js') }}" src="{{ asset('javascript/require.js') }}"></script>
        ...
    </head>
```

で回避できました．

ところが、従来`index.list.blade.php`に書いておりました`$(function(){})`がTypeScriptの中だとfireしてくれません．

[元のTypeScriptのコード：index.list.blade.ts]

```
/// <reference path="typings/index.d.ts" />

import * as dlg from "./index.list.blade.dlg";

interface IndexKeyObj{
    no:string;
    brand:string;
    type:string;
    year:string;
    class:string;
    lang:string;
    indexExists:boolean;
    generateIndex:boolean;
    status:string;
}

let indexKeyTable:Array<IndexKeyObj>=[];
/**
 * Document ready function
 */
$(function () {
        console.log("Hello World!");
        let index_rows = $("table#index-table tr.index-row");
        // Construct index data structure
        index_rows.each(function () {
            let no: string = $(this).children(".no").text();
            let brand: string = $(this).children(".brand").text();
            let type: string = $(this).children(".type").text();
            let year: string = $(this).children(".year").text();
            let bclass: string = $(this).children(".class").text();
            let lang: string = $(this).children(".lang").text();
            let indexExists: boolean = $(this).children(".index").text() === "-" ? false : true;
            let indexKeyObj: IndexKeyObj = { "no": no, "brand": brand, "type": type, "year": year, "class": bclass, "lang": lang, "indexExists": indexExists, "generateIndex": false, "status": "" };
            //console.log(index_key_obj);    
            indexKeyTable.push(indexKeyObj);
        });
```

[コンパイル後のJavaScript：index.list.blade.js]

```
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __setModuleDefault = (this && this.__setModuleDefault) || (Object.create ? (function(o, v) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, "default", { enumerable: true, value: v });
}) : function(o, v) {
    o["default"] = v;
});
var __importStar = (this && this.__importStar) || function (mod) {
    if (mod && mod.__esModule) return mod;
    var result = {};
    if (mod != null) for (var k in mod) if (k !== "default" && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mod, k)) __createBinding(result, mod, k);
    __setModuleDefault(result, mod);
    return result;
};
define("index.list.blade.dlg", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.dlgOk = void 0;
    function dlgOk(msg) {
        $("div#indexModal div.modal-header").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("div#indexModal div.modal-footer button.btn-secondary").html("OK");
        $("div#indexModal div.modal-footer button.btn-primary").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("div#indexModal div.modal-body").html(msg);
        $("div#indexModal").modal("show");
    }
    exports.dlgOk = dlgOk;
});
/// <reference path="typings/index.d.ts" />
define("index.list.blade", ["require", "exports", "index.list.blade.dlg"], function (require, exports, dlg) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    dlg = __importStar(dlg);
    var indexKeyTable = [];
    /**
     * Document ready function
     */
    $(function () {
        console.log("Hello World!");
        var index_rows = $("table#index-table tr.index-row");
        // Construct index data structure
        index_rows.each(function () {
            var no = $(this).children(".no").text();
            var brand = $(this).children(".brand").text();
            var type = $(this).children(".type").text();
            var year = $(this).children(".year").text();
            var bclass = $(this).children(".class").text();
            var lang = $(this).children(".lang").text();
            var indexExists = $(this).children(".index").text() === "-" ? false : true;
            var indexKeyObj = { "no": no, "brand": brand, "type": type, "year": year, "class": bclass, "lang": lang, "indexExists": indexExists, "generateIndex": false, "status": "" };
            //console.log(index_key_obj);    
            indexKeyTable.push(indexKeyObj);
        });
```

### 教えていただきたい点

TypeScriptの中のコードで`$(function(){})`を起動することはできないのでしょうか？方法がありましたらご教授お願い致します．

### 環境

Windows10 64bit, VSCode+Node.js, ブラウザはChromeです．

不足の情報がありましたらお知らせください．

Comment: 「`index.list.blade.ts`をコンパイルして」とありますが、これはwebpackでしょうか？使い方の雰囲気からして[laravel-mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/mixjs#typescript-support)あたりのような気がしますが。おそらくwebpackあたりを正しく使えていると`require.js`は不要になると思います。

「ところが、従来index.list.blade.phpに書いておりました$(function(){})がTypeScriptの中だとfireしてくれません．」

このとき何かしらのエラーログがブラウザのコンソールに表示されていないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．すみませんwebpack調べましたが使用しておりません．VSCodeでCtrl + Shift + Bでコンパイルしてるのみです．またブラウザにはエラーは表示されません．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

失礼いたしました．

[Is there a Main()-like function in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273366/is-there-a-main-like-function-in-typescript)

に書いてある通りでした．例えば

```
$(function () {});
```

を

```
function initWindow(){}
```

に書き換えて、コードの最後で

```
initWindow();
```

で呼び出すだけで事足りました．